# How can I recode the main method asking for user input until the user is ready to end

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to repeat the following main method infinitely so that it asks the user for input again after it runs the first time, and does the same thing over and over until the user exits:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methodselection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Please Enter A String of any length");

        String text1;
        int n1;
        text1 = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please choose a computation to run ");
        System.out.println("To Choose a computation, type in the correpsonding number to the computation you want ");
        System.out.println("The choices are: 1 = \"check if palidrone\" , 2 = \"compute rounded sum \" , 3 = \"count unique characters\" ");

        n1 = scanner.nextInt();
        if (n1 == 1) {
            System.out.println("You chose \"check if palindrone\" ");
            System.out.println(isPalindrome(text1));
        } else {
            if (n1 == 2) {
                System.out.println("You chose \" compute rounded sum \" ");
                System.out.println(roundedsum(text1));
            } else {
                if (n1 == 3) {
                    System.out.println("You chose \" count unique characters\" ");
                    System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(text1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have a look at the `while` statement. Combined with `true` it very often results in infinite repeation of some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all of your code that's in your main method in a

```
while (true or some condition)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: If someone could format that code block for me.... it's very difficult from a phone to get correct formatting.

Comment: Also, depending on exactly what you want yo happen, you may need to move variable initialization to the outside of the loop. Aka, this might need a bit of tweaking but shows the principle of what you want

Comment: I mean i just want the entire code to run again, and i texted it with just the while(true) and put the whole main method in brackets and that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){

//write your code here.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to loop infinitely, you can use a `while` loop:

```
while (true) {
    // ...
}
```

You may want to put some code before the loop, like variables that only need to be declared once:

```
Scanner scanner = ...;

String text1;
int n1;

while(true) { ... }
```

But the `while` loop is usually used with a condition, for example:

```
while (n1 != -1) { ... }
```

So, when the user inputs `-1` the loop will exit.

**Also** if you use a loop, you will get a problem. What happens is that the `nextInt()` method doesn't consume the new-line character that is entered when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so, you will need to consume it (otherwise the `nextLine()` that you are using to get the text will consume it):

```
n1 = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // consume new-line character
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop, with the check always being set to true.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class methodselection {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please Enter A String of any length");

String text1;

int n1;

text1 = scanner.nextLine();


System.out.println("Please choose a computation to run ");
System.out.println("To Choose a computation, type in the correpsonding number to the computation you want ");
System.out.println("The choices are: 1 = \"check if palidrone\" , 2 = \"compute rounded sum \" , 3 = \"count unique characters\" ");

while(true){
    n1 = scanner.nextInt();

    if (n1 == 1){
        System.out.println("You chose \"check if palindrone\" ");
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(text1));

        }


    else{
        if(n1 == 2){
                System.out.println("You chose \" compute rounded sum \" ");
                System.out.println(roundedsum(text1));
        }   
        else{
            if(n1 == 3){
                System.out.println("You chose \" count unique characters\" ");
                System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(text1));
            }
        }
    }   
    }
}
```

A while loop structure is as such:

```
while(condition){
    // do this code
}
```

as long as the condition holds, the code within the loop will keep executing. By setting the value to "true" the condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class methodselection { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Please Enter A String of any length");

String text1;

 int n1;

 text1 = scanner.nextLine();


System.out.println("Please choose a computation to run ");
System.out.println("To Choose a computation, type in the correpsonding number to the      computation you want ");
System.out.println("The choices are: 1 = \"check if palidrone\" , 2 = \"compute rounded sum \" , 3 = \"count unique characters\" ");


n1 = scanner.nextInt();

if (n1 == 1){
    System.out.println("You chose \"check if palindrone\" ");
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(text1));

    }


else{
    if(n1 == 2){
        System.out.println("You chose \" compute rounded sum \" ");
        System.out.println(roundedsum(text1));
    }   
    else{
        if(n1 == 3){
            System.out.println("You chose \" count unique characters\" ");
            System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters(text1));
        }
    }
main(null);//it will throw  run time error (StackOverflowError) //
}   
}
```